# Override plugin option by with a custom theme

Tags: theme-development, options

I'm creating a custom theme and using one of video embedding plugins from the market. There are plenty of options and among them "don't load css style", is there a way how to make it always checked when my theme is active? Author hasn't provided any define value to fix it.

it's stored in option: `fve_disable_css`

I have tried to `update_option();` on init and as well tried a filter `pre_option_fve_disable_css` but no success, any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you have the part of the plugin where the `function` is attached to an action? you have to attach your `update_option` to the same action but lower `priority` so it overrides the plugin one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin can read options on init event or just in code (during loading). All plugins are loaded before theme load. So, using init action can be too late.

Filter `pre_option_fve_disable_css` doesn't change value of the option. Instead, you have to use `option_fve_disable_css` filter. But again, it can be also too late.

You should check the handle name in wp_enqueue_script function in plugin code, which enqueues relevant css and deregister this handle in your functions.php during wp_enqueue_script event. This is the right time for such an action.